# Used `malloc` to define an array inside a function and returning that array giving segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am trying to get input from **process.txt**. So I have made a function for taking those inputs from that file.

Contents of **process.txt** file:

```
2
3
4
```

the `c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *takeInput(int *len) {

    FILE *fp = fopen("process.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fp, "%d", len);

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*len));

    for (int i = 0; i < (*len); i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    /* for (int i = 0; i < (*len); i++) { */
    /*     printf("%d\n", arr[i]); */
    /* } */
    /* printf("%p\n", arr); */

    fclose(fp);

    return arr;
}

int main() {

    int *len;
    int *arr = takeInput(len); 

    printf("%d\n", *len);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
I am unable to detect the mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 fscanf(fp, "%d", len);
```

tries to access memory that doesn't belong to it.

Declaring a pointer doesn't allocate memory for the pointed-to data. The contents of an uninitialised pointer declared with automatic storage duration are indeterminate, i.e. it may be pointing to anything in memory and it is not valid for the process to dereference it.

You don't require dynamic memory allocation here. Simply declare an `int` with automatic storage duration:

```
int len = 0;

/* Or better as: */
size_t len = 0; /* It can't be negative. */
```

And pass it's address to the function:

```
int *arr = take_input (&len);
```

The segmentation fault could also stem from reading from a `NULL` pointer, as the return value of `fopen()` was passed to `fscanf()` unchecked.

If the call to`fopen()` failed, subsequent operations would be reading from/writing to a `NULL` pointer, which would invoke undefined behaviour.

```
if (!fopen ("process.txt", "r")) {
    perror ("fopen()");
    complain ();
}
```

`malloc()` too, returns `NULL` to indicate failure. A similar check should be done for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion regarding `len` about whether to use its value `len` or its address `&len` which led to your defining it as a pointer.  You should define `len` as an integer with type `int`. and pass its address to `fscanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *takeInput(int *len) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("process.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n",
                "process.txt", strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", len) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid length\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (*len));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate array\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (*len); i++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
            break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return arr;
}

int main(void) {
    int len;
    int *arr = takeInput(&len); 
    if (arr != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```